shift + enter does not work to run a code selection in VS Code with Python 3.12 in Windows 10 but works with 3.11 (and 3.9)
After trying hard to find a way to make VS Code 1.92 (31-07-2024) run a code selection with the keyboard shortcut shift + enter, with a 3.12 Python compiler, in Windows 10, I gave up.
My solution was to use Python 3.11 instead.
When selecting one line the code would open the terminal and run just that line fine. However, multiple lines were not possible, the terminal would do nothing. When using the option "Run Selected Text" the message <stdin>:2: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\O' would appear when a two line if function was selected.
The expected behaviour was to select a multiple line code and after hitting shift + enter that selected code would run.
The working solution at this moment is to use Python version 3.11 instead which works (and before that with the 3.9 version was working).
Tried solutions:

uninstall and reinstall vs code and python
check the "run selection" command in the keyboard shortcuts menu available in the settings wheel.
create a virtual environment in the interpreter
use python.experiments.optInto: ["pythonREPLSmartSend"] as indicated by Microsoft

Other consulted links (which did not work):

Selection of multiple lines and running code (shift+enter) doesn't do the cursor down. · Issue #22539 · microsoft/vscode-python
VS Code: Shift+Enter does not send code to Python Interactive - why? - Super User

tips:

use the create restoration utility available in windows before you do something drastic
the final install for python and VS code was for one user only, which is the standard option (when you select all users some options change and I don't know if this is important)
use the create paths option for the environment variables for both python (important) and VS code (don't know if it is important)


I also encountered this problem, and after trying, I found that the reason why 'shift+enter' fails is that some Python code triggers syntax warnings.
import sys; sys.path += ['D:\python'] 

It will fail because the Python terminal will prompt:<stdin>: 1: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\ p'
but
 import sys; sys.path += [r'D:\python'] 

Will make the shift+enter function properly
Therefore, I speculate that the reason for the failure of shift+enter is due to the partial code penalty of Python 3.12 syntax warning mechanism
But I don't understand how to solve this problem except to downgrade the version to 3.11
